# Way to load data between dates in report viewer in C#

Tags: c#, sql-server, reportviewer

I am trying to get data between two dates in a report viewer control in windows forms. Filtering report data, so I modified the dataset using parameters to

```
select SN,invoice_date,product_code........ where invoice_date >= @date1 and invoice_date <= @date2
```

I tried this also

```
select SN,invoice_date,product_code........ where invoice_date between @date1 and @date2
```

But the query is not returing any data, the datatype I used in SQL Server is date, and I changed the properties of the dataset @date1 and @date2 into date. So the problem is the datetimepicker am using is not working as it is adding time to the value. And I tried to validate the datetimepicker into something like

```
datetimepicker1.value.date.toshortdatestring()   even tried  datetimepicker1.value.tostring()
```

But the problem is, it will generate an error that system.datetime cannot be convert into string. I even change the datatype of the @date1 and @date2 into varchar in the dataset properties but still not loading.

So this is the code tried

```
this.Sales_InvoiceTableAdapter.FillByget(this.ProductREP.Sales_Invoice, ProductFrom.Value, ProductTo.Value, txtproductcode.Text);

this.Sales_InvoiceTableAdapter.FillByget(this.ProductREP.Sales_Invoice, ProductFrom.Value.Date, ProductTo.Value.Date, txtproductcode.Text);
```

What am I missing? I am using C# with SQL Server.

Comment: Please update your answer with the signature of your FillByget method and the values and types of your ProductFrom.Value and ProductTo.Value

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming that the signature of `Sales_InvoiceTableAdapter.FillByget` is `FillByget(string invoice, DateTime from, DateTime to, string productCode)`, then you should not need to convert to a string and you should check you're setting the time portion appropriately.

```cs
this.Sales_InvoiceTableAdapter.FillByget(this.ProductREP.Sales_Invoice, ProductFrom.Value.Date, ProductTo.Value.Date.AddDays(1), txtproductcode.Text);
```

Given a `ProductFrom.Value` and `ProductTo.Value` equal to `2020-04-28T10:55:00`, the above code will result in `ProductFrom.Value = 2020-04-28T00:00:00`and `ProductTo.Value = 2020-04-29T00:00:00`.
If you want to only get values on that specific day (excluding midnight), then subtract 1 second from your final `to` value. e.g. `ProductTo.Value.Date.AddDays(1).Subtract(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1))`.